# Stolz Angle $M$ range

Tags: complex-analysis

I refer to Stolz angle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), the region of the open unit disk where $|1-z|\leq M(1-|z|)$ for some $M$.

My question is, are there any conditions on $M$? Can $M$ take any real value?

I suppose $M$ cannot be negative, since $|z|<1$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, M can be any non-negative real number.

Comment: Actually no, $M$ can be any _positive_ real. If you let $M=0$ you get the empty set...

Answer (score 1):

By triangle inequality, we have $|1-z|\ge |1-|z||=1-|z|>0$. So
$$
  M> \frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|}\ge 1.
$$